# socket closed trying to connect to Axis2 web service deployed on weblogic

Tags: java, web-services, deployment, cxf, weblogic-10.x

I have an application that is using Apache CXF to communicate with Axis2 web service. On the test environment everything went smoothly, moving to the production environment the following exception occurs:

```
INFO: Interceptor has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Could not send Message.
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:64)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:220)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:466)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:299)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:251)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:75)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:124)
    at $Proxy131.retrieveAccountSummary(Unknown Source)
.
.
.

Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Socket Closed
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.setOption(PlainSocketImpl.java:201)
    at java.net.Socket.setTcpNoDelay(Socket.java:850)
    at weblogic.net.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:326)
    at weblogic.net.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:411)
    at weblogic.net.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:241)
    at weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:176)
    at weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:242)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleHeadersTrustCaching(HTTPConduit.java:1836)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.onFirstWrite(HTTPConduit.java:1794)
    at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractWrappedOutputStream.write(AbstractWrappedOutputStream.java:42)
    at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractThresholdOutputStream.write(AbstractThresholdOutputStream.java:70)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1854)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:66)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:595)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
    ... 40 more
```

as far as I was told, nothing on the network is terminating the connections, and I increased the ConnectionTimeout and the RecievingTimeout from cxf configuration but no use.

Both applications are deployed on weblogic 10.3.2.0 on different servers, I need some guidance on where could the problem be? what could cause a socket to be closed? I don't want to be looking into things that are not related to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is solved now.

The CXF client was accessing the WSDL without any problems, but in the WSDL the service port address was set to `localhost` instead of the IP address of the server:

```
<wsdl:service name="serviceName">
    <wsdl:port binding="tns:servicePortBinding" name="servicePort">
        <soap:address location="http://localhost:7001/app/services/service/" /> 
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

my application was trying to send the requests to `localhost` and of course a `SocketException` was the result.

The soap address is set to `localhost` in the original WSDL, however, when I created Axis2 web service and deployed it on the test environment, the address was getting updated to the machine IP address (which did not happen on the UAT).

I'm not sure how and when the soap address gets updated, but  I guess when the machine has more than one network interface, Axis leaves the address as is or maybe updates it to `localhost`.

Now to fix this issue I had to [override the service address](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/client-http-transport-including-ssl-support.html) as follows:

```
port = service.getMyServicePort();
BindingProvider provider = (BindingProvider) port;
String endpointAddress = "http://<ip address>:7001/app/services/service/";
provider.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, endpointAddress);
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this happen after always a fixed duration = connection timeout like 30 or 60 seconds, or is it instantly failing?

If instant, is there established connectivity between both servers, i.e. no firewall or other restrictions in between - does `ping` or `telnet` work between both servers?

Is test setup exactly same as Live , i.e. WLS and CXF versions are same?
Also see http://osdir.com/ml/users-cxf-apache/2010-03/msg00407.html

Comment: thanks for your reply, the exception happens within 5 secs (increasing the ConnectionTimeout and the RecievingTimeout didn't help) and telnet worked fine on the same port.
I use the same versions of CXF and weblogic in the test and production environments.
I actually stumbled upon the same link you suggested and upgraded the CXF version, on the test environment it kept working but on the production CXF started to read the WSDL location as if it is deployed on localhost (i.e. replaced the host ip with 'localhost') so, I reverted back to CXF 2.1.3

Comment: @Ahmad: 5 secs usually indicates weblogic cannot connect at all to the other server and the timeout dont come into picture? is there some https url or try `setConnectionTimeout(0);` which means no timeout at all. Also try `setMaxRetransmits` to 3 or so

Comment: actually, the setMaxRetransmits is set to 3 :)

I'll continue working on upgrading the CXF version as suggested by the link you referred to. Previously, I only upgraded the CXF jar and added a missing dependency. the following exception occurred: `SocketException invoking http://localhost:7001/QAR%20WS/services/RetSrvc/: Socket Closed`
which is wired because I provided the following WSDL location `http://10.20.11.2:7001/QAR%20WS/services/RetSrvc?wsdl` which is an IP for a different machine.
I'll make sure this time that I'm using the correct versions of CXF dependencies.